# in interface builder what is accessibility menu for?

Tags: xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, interface-builder

with the newer sdk we can see a menu named accessibility in identity inspector.What does it do and how we can use it in application?

Comment: i think it's to make your applications easily accessible for people with disabilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That menu is part of the accessibility interface, which allows you to make your application more usable by those with disabilities.

Through the various components, including attributes like labels to hook in to the VoiceOver system, traits to describe a control's position and state, hints to describe the uses of a control, zoom, high contrast modes, and much more, you can significantly improve the accessibility of your application (in addition to providing some benefits to those who happen to like these features even if they have no disability).

The [Accessibility Programming Guide for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Accessibility_on_iPhone/Accessibility_on_iPhone.html) provides all the details and a great jumping off point to get started with accessibility in iPhone development.